# hotkey to mark the current cell and make it a text cell

Tags: front-end, cells, style, keyboard

In order to write to a Text cell, you usually just start typing. Then you find out that you are writing in an Input cell. Then you want to convert the current cell to a Text cell. In order to to this you

1. have to click on the cell bracket in order to select the cell
   itself,
2. then hit Alt+7

**I want to combine this alltogether to a single Alt+7** (provided that the focus is just inside a cell, the normal behaviour in other situations shall not be altered to maintain as much compatibility as possible).

Remarks:

1.) I would also like this for the other possibilities from **Format>Style**, i.e. not just Alt+7 but rather Alt+1 .... Alt+9.

2.) If Alt++ and Alt+- are not yet bound, I would like Alt++ to **promote** the currently assigned state of the cell up by one (i.e. Number from Alt+number down by one, but no further than 1, because the assignments are made that way) and I would like Alt+- to **downgrade** currently assigned state of the cell by one (i.e. increment the number from Alt+number by 1, but no further than 9).

If Alt+ and Alt- are already bound, what about Alt+> andd Alt+<  ?

Answer (score 6):

Wolfram Research has "sort of" fixed this annoyance in *Mathematica* 10.3:

If you start typing a Machine Learning algorithm running in the front end detects that you are writing text and offers you these options:

[image]

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to convert to text cell

[image]

………………………………………………………………………………………………

In *Mathematica* versions: 8, 9 and 10: you can save yourself the inefficiency of the mouse by hitting the following shortcut keys:

<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>  then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[Up Arrow]</kbd> to select the cell

then finally hit <kbd>Alt+7</kbd>

………………………………………………………………………………………………

(a very simple way is to reverse) just <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> delete your characters until the cell is empty;

then hit <kbd>Alt+7</kbd>;

then type your characters again

Comment: "Machine Learning algorithm": Does this mean, that I first have to install the framework described in http://www.unisoftwareplus.at/download/mlf/2.1/mlf-2.1.0-documentation.pdf?

Comment: I have seen, I misunderstood it. After starting to type the second word, the shown choice is displayed. Normally I do not constantly look at the screen when writing. Ok, Tab seems to be the key to convert the input to a text cell. Which key is denoted by the S in a square?